How to insert the selected data from a popup LOV item?
I'm relatively new to Oracle APEX and currently using version 22.2.1. I have three tables in my database setup:

INVENTAIRE (idInventaire NUMBER, Inv_Date TIMESTAMP, ...)
ARTICLE (idArticle NUMBER, Code_Article VARCHAR2, ...)
ARTICLE_HAS_INVENTAIRE (Inventaire_idInventaire NUMBER, Article_idArticle NUMBER, ...)

My goal is to create a form for operators to plan their periodic inventories. The process involves operators specifying the date for the next inventory and selecting the articles relevant to that inventory.
To achieve this, I've created a form based on the above tables using the following SQL Query:
SELECT
    i.idInventaire,
    i.Inv_date,
    idArticle,
    ar.code_article
FROM
    Inventaire i
JOIN
    Article_has_Inventaire ai ON i.idInventaire = ai.Inventaire_idInventaire
JOIN
    Article ar ON ai.Article_idArticle = ar.idArticle;

The idInventaire and idArticle columns are hidden because I've set up a trigger to automatically increment them. The Inv_date is configured as a date picker, and Code_Article as a Popup LOV displaying all Code_Article options from the ARTICLE table.
I've also added a "Save" button. When clicked, it should insert a new record into the INVENTAIRE table with the specified INV_DATE, and for each selected Code_Article, new records should be inserted into the ARTICLE_HAS_INVENTAIRE table.
Here's the server-side code I'm using in the button's dynamic action:
BEGIN
  -- Insert a new inventory with the specified date
  INSERT INTO Inventaire (Inv_Date)
  VALUES (:P_DATE_PICKER);

  -- Retrieve the ID of the newly inserted inventory
  DECLARE
    v_idInventaire NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(idInventaire) INTO v_idInventaire FROM Inventaire;
    
    -- Insert selected articles into Article_has_Inventaire
    FOR rec IN (SELECT Code_Article FROM ARTICLE WHERE Code_Article IN (:P_POPUP_LOV))
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO Article_has_Inventaire (Article_idArticle, Inventaire_idInventaire)
      VALUES (rec.Code_Article, v_idInventaire);
    END LOOP;
  END;
END;

when i check my tables , new records ar added to my table INVENTAIRE , but no record is inserted to the ARTICLE_HAS_INVENTAIRE table , does someone can figure out why ?
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on improving this setup or addressing any potential issues with my approach. Thank you!

The reason nothing is inserted in "Article_has_Inventaire" is that the statement WHERE Code_Article IN (:P_POPUP_LOV) does not return any rows.  Suppose the selected values are 1,2 and 3 then the value of :P_POPUP_LOV will be 1:2:3 and the where clause will be parsed as WHERE Code_Article IN ('1:2:3'). You don't want that, you need WHERE Code_Article IN ('1','2','3') instead.
Solution: use the APEX_STRING api to convert the colon-separated string to a nested table with the individual selected values
SELECT Code_Article 
  FROM ARTICLE 
 WHERE Code_Article IN (SELECT column_value FROM table(apex_string.split(: P_POPUP_LOV,':'))

A couple of notes, since you say that you're new to APEX.

For processing form data, the pattern is not to use dynamic actions but page processing. New APEX developers usually try to do everything with dynamic actions, but that is not the best way. In APEX, a form consist of a pre-rendering processes to get the data and a native page processing process to save the data in the database. No dynamic actions are needed. Try this out by creating a simple report and form via the wizard and check what APEX generates. If the form is on a sql query like in your question then still use page processing, not dynamic actions.
here is a SO answer on a similar question - this might be a good reference
It is strongly encouraged to name all the page items P<page_number>_ITEM_NAME. That is because page item names are unique throughout the application and belong to a page (for maintaining session state, when clearing cache etc). Not following this best practice is guaranteed to give you headaches.


Thank you for your assistance, Sir.
I attempted to use the code you provided. However, upon submitting, I encountered an error message:
'Ajax call returned server error ORA-01722: invalid number for Execute Server-Side Code.' Could you please help me understand and resolve this issue?"

Run the page in debug mode - check the docs - something is wrong with the dynamic action. Without access to your environment it's very hard to help you with such little info

As I suggested earlier... don't do this with a dynamic action. It is adding unnecessary complexity to your form.
